# How can I get the dots that surround some elements to go away/become solid lines?

Tags: html, css, razor

How can I get the dots that surround some elements to go away/become solid lines?

A page I'm working on has some arguably ugly dotted lines around some elements:

[image]

I thought I had the solution when I changed this in the page's css file from:

```
#trSalesTotal td
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0FE;
    border-top: 2px dotted #a9a9a9;
    border-left: 2px dotted #a9a9a9;
    border-right: 2px dotted #a9a9a9;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #a9a9a9;
}
```

...to:

```
#trSalesTotal td
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0FE;
    border-top: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-left: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
}
```

...but even after saving those changes and mashing Ctrl+R in the browser, I still see the same thing. Searching for "dotted" in my project now produces zero results! Where are these measles emanating from, and what is the antidote?

I even tried adding this:

```
#trSalesTotal
{
    border-top: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
}
```

...but still no go; I inspect the element in Chrome Dev Tools `(<tr id="trSalesTotal">)` and see no "border-*" properties at all, neither dotted nor solid. In fact, I don't see in the html why there is even a "wrapper" around the Sales Total min and max values - who is putting it there? This is the html:

```
<tr id="trSalesTotal">
    <td style="background-color: transparent; border-width: 0;">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LabelSalesTotal)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormSalesTotalMin)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormSalesTotalMin, new {style = "width: 134px;"})
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormSalesTotalMax)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormSalesTotalMax, new {style = "width: 109px;"})
    </td>
</tr>
```

BTW, I also tried replacing:

```
<td style="background-color: transparent; border-width: 0;">
```

...with:

```
<td>
```

...but still the ugly dots appear. So where in tarnation is it getting this dotted business from?

Comment: Did you look for dashed? It could be dashed.

Comment: did you clear your cache? old css may have been cached by the browser.

Comment: @crush: No "dash" in the project, dash it all (I wanted to undash it all).

Comment: @user1: Yes, I mashed Ctrl+R in Chrome, which should clear the cache.

Comment: as far as i know, ctrl + R is a normal reload, try ctrl + shift + R

Comment: look in other browsers to check, not just Chrome. Safari is usually good if you "Reset" or choose clear cache. Also, usually you have to hold a shift key down in different browsers to actually clear cache, not just reload. Unless that option is set

Comment: Did you use the "inspect element" and make sure that the CSS isn't getting overridden elsewhere?

Comment: and also you can use firebug to check how it is getting the dotted line.

Comment: @crush: Yes, I think I mention that I did F12 to inspect in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: And what did it show in the CSS panel on the right side? Did it show dotted and where it was coming from?

Comment: Any chance we can inspect a live version of this bug?

Comment: @user1: No, ctrl + shift + R don't help, either.

Comment: @crush: Nope, no "dotted" is shown anywhere in the element inspection tools of CDT.

Comment: @crush: No, this is not live; it is barely on life support, and that locally only.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You could try putting these rules into a separate sheet, and including it at the bottom of the HEAD section. You could set it with Javascript. You could set a more specific rule that would override this. I'm stumped though. If it doesn't show dotted in CDT, but shows in the browser, that's a first.

Comment: When you change the color or the thickness of the border, does it change on the screen? Or is it stuck at 2 pixels and grayish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried adding !important, you added it to:

```
#trSalesTotal
```

Instead of:

```
#trSalesTotal td
```

So give this a shot:

```
#trSalesTotal td
{
    border-top: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
}
```

Also you could write this more simply:

```
#trSalesTotal td {
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried both. Good tip on the border streamlining, though! It's one of those things that I "knew" but didn't notice looking at it.

Comment: Have you tried adding the desired CSS directly to the HTML element? Is the desired result still not achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Criminy, here's what happened:

This file had all the CSS contained within it, so I moved it all out to a separate .CSS file and linked to that. To make a long story short, I ended up putting the CSS back in the file, temporarily, and commented out the call to that external style sheet.

So, the rules are being applied based on what is (again) contained in the cshtml file. That's as it should be. I changed the "dotted" there to "solid" and it's better now (still needs some work/cleanup).

BUT! I still find it strange that CDT did not see the CSS rules within the page as affecting the rendered html, yet it was pointing at the no-longer referenced stylesheet! What's up with that?